# How to read JSON files from the www folder of an Android Phonegap App using AngularJS

Tags: android, json, angularjs, cordova

I'm trying to read local JSON file located in the www folder of my phoneGap application.

Using the $resource service of angular to load the file using didn't worked.

```
 $resource('/app/www/app/Commun/JSonFiles/:fileName.json', {}, {
            query: { method: 'GET', params: {}, isArray: true }
        });
```

Always get an 404.

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to use the file:///android_asset to access resources located in the www folder.

```
 $resource('file:///android_asset/www/app/Commun/JSonFiles/:fileName.json', {}, {
            query: { method: 'GET', params: {}, isArray: true }
        })
```

Code sample can be found here: https://gist.github.com/cbrains/8659946

Comment: I feel like giving you a beer right now! Thx so much!